# Vba cell content linked to other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, reference, cell

I need to have my excel workbook with cells continuously mirroring the same value as filled in another worksheet placed in a different folder. What I'm trying to do is to create a vba routine associated to a command button that changes the cells reference to a specific file. I need to repeat the operation for several cells.

My code for now is:

```
Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
Dim ppath As String
Dim pathC As String
Dim pathF As String
Dim compath As String
Dim cell0 As Range

'Open the file dialog starting from the active workbook path and get the desired file path and filename
ppath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
diaFolder.InitialFileName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
diaFolder.Title = "Selezionare il file excel di contratto"
diaFolder.Show
'Range("IC_Files_Path").Value = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
compath = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
Set diaFolder = Nothing
pathC = Replace(compath, ppath, "")

' divide sstr as the desired file path + fileName + desired sheet
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Dim fileName As String
fileName = objFSO.GetFileName(pathC)

pathF = Replace(pathC, "/" & fileName, "")
Set cell0 = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
sstr = "='" & pathF & "[" & fileName & "]Info Generali'!"

'set the cell value mirroring the corresponding cell in the desired file

'cell0.Offset(12, 3).Formula = sstr & Cells(43, 4).Address(True, True) (alternative option)
cell0.Offset(12, 3).Value = sstr & "$D$43"
```

In this last line cell value is becoming `'C:\MyPath\WorkbookFolder[fileName]DesiderShetet'!$D$43`
everything is working fine, but the point is that for every single cell where I set the path as in the line cell0.Offset... the routine opens a browse window asking me to re-select the file and then another dialog asking me to choose which sheet to refer. Is it possible to deactivate these windows to popup for each cell and to force the link as composed? Otherwise it would be long as it is asking these two steps for every cell with changed path.

Anyone had this problem before?

Thanks in advance

Tryed different methods to attribute cell value (one is in the code as comment) but gained no change

Comment: Have you tried putting `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the beginning of your code and then turning it back on at the end with `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Comment: If you have more cells to update, then add those updates after the end of the posted code?

Comment: Thank you Glenn G for your answer. It works, but with this metod it is as if I didn't select any file in the loop I suppressed with your tip, so the obtaind cell content is an inconsistent link pointing to nowhere (as an example i get <='C:\[Contratto WISCO-IMPIANTO VUOTATURA[Contratto 6900018886.xlsx]Info Generali]Contratto WISCO-IMPIANTO VUOTAT'!$D$43> instead of <='\Contratto WISCO-IMPIANTO VUOTATURA[Contratto 6900018886.xlsx]Info Generali'!$D$43>)